# Why aren't My.Settings saving?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a setting in `My.Settings` named `Categories`. So inside a module I have a public sub which runs this code:

```
Public Sub DeclareCategories()
    Dim currentCategory As String
    '   GET CURRENT CATEGORIES
    currentCategory = My.Settings.Categories

    '   ADD THE CATEGORY
    My.Settings.Categories = currentCategory & frmNewCategory.txtCategoryName.Text & ","
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

The user will then update the `My.Settings.Categories` value upon clicking a button in that form `frmNewCategory`. Here is the code for button:

```
If txtCategoryName.Text <> "" Then
    Try
        DeclareCategories()
        MsgBox("Successfully added the new category!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

Else
    MsgBox("Please enter a category name before adding.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

End If
```

For some reason, my settings do not save. The `Categories` is a string also. I even tried removing all the `currentCategory` stuff and just keep:

```
My.Settings.Categories = frmNewCategory.txtCategoryName.Text
My.Settings.Save()
```

But it still didn't save the setting. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the scope of that setting? Are you sure that it's not saved, or you just can see anything in the Project Settings? If you do something like `Dim currentCategory As String = My.Settings.Categories` after saving the setting or in Form.Load(), do you have and empty string, an error or something else? (If the scope is User, it usually works :)

Comment: Yeah the scope is set to user, which is why I'm quite concerned. I can't see anything in the project settings after running the code.

Comment: You won't see anything there, unless you inserted it manually (you'll find your strings in `c:\[UserName]\AppData\Local\[YourProjectName]\[ProjectURL]\[ProjectVersion]\user.config`). What's important is if those settings are stored or not. Try to assign a value to the setting, `.Save()`, then close the application. When you realod it, assign the setting to a variable (in Form.Load(), maybe) and see what happens when you debug it.

Comment: will do! thanks heaps.

Comment: try saving your settings without debugging and see if they save

Comment: You didn't post any code that actually uses My.Settings.Categories.  Which does explain why "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Remind that My.Settings are saved only on the computer who saves them.
Example : Your Categories Setting will be saved on a file on your computer.

If you save a setting in "Categories" and put your executable application on another computer, the "Categories" setting will be empty.

Also, check the string `currentCategory & frmNewCategory.txtCategoryName.Text` to make sure that the string isn't in fact empty.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, with VS 2022, I created an empty Windows Forms .NET App. Then I defined a setting "HeyYou" in user's scope with a default value.
In project settings/Application I checked  "Save My.Settings on shutdown".

```
public class Form1
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      MyTextBox.Text = My.Settings.HeyYou
End Class
```

But it does not work, although above mentioned user.config under AppData contains a certain value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="HeyYou" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\scratch</value>
            </setting>
        </FMyApp.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I bother about this phenomenom on several machines for months. My guess is, it came with VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem is with how My.Settings saves info.  The physical storage location uses the application revision to create a folder where the settings are saved in a file named user.config.  If the rev changes, the storage location changes.

Verify this by going to '\User[you]\AppData\Local[Your Appname][Your AppName].exe_Url_[unique id][current rev]'.  The easiest way to find it is to just search '\User[You]\AppData' for the name of your project.  When you get down to that [unique id] folder you may see a number of folders based on your project revisions under it. If you do, that may be your problem.

I had written a wrapper program for Vis Studio that changed the project build level in order to trigger a source code backup if I modified the project.  Worked great but it causes My.Settings to return IsEmpty=True every time you try to access a property.

If this is happening to you, look for something that's changing the project revision.